# long division with no numbers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory

Im stumped by the following brain teaser:

Solve the following long division problem. Each letter represents a unique digit ($0$ - $9$)

$$
\require{enclose}
\begin{array}{r}
                    B  \\[-3pt]
XZD \enclose{longdiv}{BUMG} \\[-3pt]
         \underline{APZK} \\[-3pt]
                    ABU  \\[-3pt]      
\end{array}
$$

im just looking for a first step hint, not the entire solution, or a similar simpler example.

Comment: I'm stumped with the image itself. Is there anyway that you can make it look like a standard illustration of long-division?

Comment: @barakmanos this is the way I received the question, that's why I didn't type it up again in my own format

Comment: Well, any chance you can tell us what's the divisor and what's the dividend to begin with?

Comment: @barakmanos I didn't have any more info than the question as is. I assumed that the divisor was XZD, the dividend was the 4 digit number BUMG, and the quotient was B

Comment: @Frentos yes...does that make it easier to solve? is it a trial and error method?

Comment: @barakmanos What country are you from? In the US, that's what long division looks like. (Some other countries do it differently, with the numbers shuffled around a bit, but with the same algorithm.)

Comment: @barakmanos I'm guessing either Israel or some Arab country? According to the internet, you do it the same way as us but flipped horizontally.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can separate it into cases on $B$ (it is easy to see that $B\not=0,1,5,9$), and find the values in the following order : $B\rightarrow A\rightarrow X\rightarrow Z,D,K\rightarrow P\rightarrow U,M,G$.

For $B=2$, we have $A=0,1$. But if $A=0$, then 
$$(BU)=(2UMG)-(PZK)\ge 2000-999=1001$$
So, $A=1$. Also, if $X\le 8$, then
$$(2UMG)=2\times (XZD)+(12U)\le 2\times 899+129=1927$$
So, $X=9$.

Here, let $[n]$ be the right-most two digits of $n$. Then, since we have
$$[2\times (ZD)]=[ZK]$$
we have $Z=0$.  But $(2UMG)=2\times (90D)+(12U)\le 2\times 909+129=1947$.

Similarly, you can do for $B=3,4,6,7,8$. In the following, I'll write the outlines.

For $B=3$, we have $A=2,X=9$. Now $Z=4,5$.

Case 1 : If $Z=4$, then $D=7,K=1,P=8,U=0,M=7\quad\Rightarrow\quad D=M$.

Case 2 : If $Z=5$, then $D=0,P=8,K=0\quad\Rightarrow\quad D=K$.

For $B=4$, we have $A=3,X=9$. Now $Z=0,6$.

Case 1 : If $Z=0$, then $D=2,P=6,K=8$. So, $$(4UMG)=4\times 902+(34U)\le 4\times 902+349=3957.$$

Case 2 : If $Z=6$, then $D=5,P=8,K=0,U=2,M=0\quad \Rightarrow\quad K=M$.

For $B=6$, we have $A=5,X=9$. Now $(Z,D,K)=(2k,1,6),(2k-1,9,4)\quad\Rightarrow\quad B=K\quad\text{or}\quad X=D$.

For $B=7$, we have $A=6, X=9$. Now $(Z,D,K)=(3,4,8),(8,3,1)$.

Case 1 : If $(Z,D,K)=(3,4,8)$, then $P=5,U=2,M=1,G=0$. This is sufficient.

Case 2 : If $(Z,D,K)=(8,3,1)$, then $P=8\quad\Rightarrow \quad Z=P$.

For $B=8$, we have $A=7,X=9, Z=1,D=4,K=2,P=3,M=9\quad\Rightarrow\quad M=X$.

Hence, the answer is 
$$A=6,\quad B=7,\quad D=4,\quad G=0,\quad K=8,$$$$\quad M=1,\quad P=5,\quad U=2,\quad X=9,\quad Z=3$$

Comment: could you explain the statement: [ 2 x ZD ] = [ZK] ?

Comment: @dimebucker91: You'll see the meaning by putting every number from $00$ to $99$ in $ZD$ as the followings : $ZD=00$ is possible because $[2\times (\color{red}{0}0)]=\color{red}{0}0$. (The red parts are the places where $Z$ exist.) $ZD=01$ is possible because $[2\times (\color{red}{0}1)]=\color{red}{0}2$, ..., $ZD=11$ is not possible because $[2\times (11)]=22$, ..., $ZD=33$ is not possible because $[2\times (33)]=66$, ..., $ZD=99$ is possible because $[2\times (\color{red}{9}9)]=\color{red}{9}8$. So, we have $Z=0,9$, but $Z$ cannot be $9$ because of $X=9$. Thus, we have $Z=0$.

Comment: why is it so obvious that $b \neq 5,9$? even before we show that X must be 9 ?

Comment: @dimebucker91: For $B=5$, if $D$ is even, then $K=0\Rightarrow G=U$. If $D$ is odd, then $K=5$. For $B=9$, $A$ has to be $8$. If $X\le 8$, then $(9UMG)=9\times (XZD)+(89U)\le 9\times 899+899=8990$. So, $X=9$. So, yes, I used that $X=9$. (I omitted the details just because I thought these were "very short".) By the way, do you understand the statement in your first comment?

Comment: yes, i think i do now, you are saying that since 2 x 9ZD = 1PZK, then the right most digits of 2 x ZD should be ZK, since the 2 x 9 is the 1 p part, where P in this case has to be 8 --- is this correct?

Comment: @dimebucker91: For your third comment, yes. Similarly, $Z=9$ if $D\ge 5$. For the fourth, correct.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is exactly equivalent to the equations: $$BUMG = B * XZD + ABU$$ and $$APZK = B * XZD$$ so we also have $$BUMG = APZK + ABU$$

Hint:
$XZD = \dfrac{BUMG-ABU}{B} = \dfrac{BUMG}{B} - \dfrac{ABU}{B} \approx 1000 - \dfrac{ABU}{B}$, but $XZD$ has 3 digits.  What does that tell you about possible values for $X$ (think about ranges of values for $\dfrac{ABU}{B}$)?

It may help to make a grid to track the possible remaining values for the digit variables as you work.  $B \ne 0$ and $B \ne 1$ (can you see why?). None of the leading digits will be $0$.

There is some trial and error in these kinds of problems, but a lot of it is reasoning about ranges of numbers and digit patterns that occur in additions and multiplications.

Comment: i understand why BUMG/B is roughly 1000, but why do you expect XZD to be equal to that? why do you ignore the ABU?

Comment: I still don't quite see how that's useful.. i can deduce that B=A+1, so that ABU/B <100, but i don't think that tells me what any of the values must be